# Ag grid - this.gridapi.foreachnode not printing anything

Tags: angular, scope, ag-grid

Here is the .html file -

```
<ag-grid-angular
#agGrid
style="width: 100%; height: 100%; "
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[sideBar]="sidebar"
[ngClass]="theme"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[domLayout]="domLayout"
rowSelection="multiple"
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
(gridReady)="OnGridReady($event)"
>
```

I am inserting data into rowData in the ngOnInit() function as follows -

```
ngOnInit()
{
    fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((out) => {
        this.rowData = out.data;
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

In the OnGridReady() function, after initialising the gridApi and ColumnApi, I am using this.gridApi.foreachnode to iterate over all the rowData and print them in console as follows -

```
OnGridReady(params)
{
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
    console.log("printing data ->")
    this.gridApi.forEachNode((node, index)=>
    {
        console.log(node.data.id + '-' + node.data.employee_name);
        console.log();
    });
}
```

But nothing is being displayed in console. Besides, there is no error or anything. Where am I going wrong? Is there some scope problem in using the arrow function in foreachnode() ?

Also, if I use a button to call a function which uses gridapi to iterate over the data, it is working. Why is this?

Comment: Try to put some message outside of the gridApi.forEachNode loop. OnGridReady is called before it fetches data so there is nothing to log.

Comment: it is a timing issue,  ngOnInit is an angular hook whereas OnGridReady is ag grid lifecycle hook. your data is not fetched from server when grid is being initialized. You can call fetch in onGridReady and do api.forEachNode in .then()

Comment: @user3551808 can u tell specifically how to do this. I want to display the data after data gets loaded.

Comment: @PratikBhat still no output.

Answer (score 0):

Grid Options provides an event 'onRowDataChanged'. in html, i am adding (rowDataChanged)="function_to_iterate($event)" this seems to have done the trick.